Can I change WinUI 3 ListViewItemPresenter selection indicator placement from left to top?
I want to create a horizontally scrollable ListView with a selection indicator located at the top or bottom.
Can I achieve that by restyling ListViewItemPresenter or anyhow else reusing it?

I suggest you could try to customize the ControlTemplate of the ListViewItem.
You can modify properties on the ListViewItemPresenter to control the selection check box, item positioning, and brush colors for visual states.

I'm not sure if you can restyle ListViewItemPresenter.
The selection indicator is a Border with no name, so you need to find it by yourself. In the example below, I'm using the CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions NuGet package.
private void MemberListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not ListView listView ||
        listView.ContainerFromItem(listView.SelectedItem) is not ListViewItem selectedListViewItem ||
        selectedListViewItem.FindDescendant<ListViewItemPresenter>() is not { } selectedListViewItemPresenter ||
        selectedListViewItemPresenter.FindDescendants().OfType<Border>().LastOrDefault() is not Border selectionIndicator)
    {
        return;
    }

    selectionIndicator.Width = 64;
    selectionIndicator.Height = 3;
    selectionIndicator.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, -8);
    selectionIndicator.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    selectionIndicator.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
}

